# PHP Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /app/public/wp-includes/wp-db.php

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Any suggestions on how to solve this? I can log in, about every-second time I click on something I get HTTP 505 error, I reload and it loads fine. Rinse & repeat.
On the front-end, sometimes I get a critical error, (and the site fails to load, reload & it's working) but not as often.

***Debug log:***

```
07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] **PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /app/public/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1612**
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/wp:0
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   2. include() /usr/local/bin/wp:4
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   3. include() phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php:8
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   4. WP_CLI\bootstrap() phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/wp-cli.php:23
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   5. WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process() phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/bootstrap.php:75
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   6. WP_CLI\Runner->start() phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php:23
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   7. WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress() phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php:1032
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   8. require() phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php:1105
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP   9. require_wp_db() /app/public/wp-settings.php:109
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP  10. wpdb->__construct() /app/public/wp-includes/load.php:435
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP  11. wpdb->db_connect() /app/public/wp-includes/wp-db.php:639
[07-May-2019 02:18:39 UTC] PHP  12. mysqli_real_connect() /app/public/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1612
```

---

***wp-db file (error line)***

```
/*
         * Deprecated in 3.9+ when using MySQLi. No equivalent
         * $new_link parameter exists for mysqli_* functions.
         */

    $new_link     = defined( 'MYSQL_NEW_LINK' ) ? MYSQL_NEW_LINK : true;
            $client_flags = defined( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS' ) ? MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS : 0;
    
            if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
                $this->dbh = mysqli_init();
    
                $host    = $this->dbhost;
                $port    = null;
                $socket  = null;
                $is_ipv6 = false;
    
    $host_data = $this->parse_db_host( $this->dbhost );
                if ( $host_data ) {
                    list( $host, $port, $socket, $is_ipv6 )= $host_data;
```

**last line ---> 1612 error line**

Comment: Dailbor, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can improve your chances of getting a response by improving your title. Something like "Intermittent mysql connection issue in wordpress v?.??" Include MySql version and how it's running. Are you using lamp? Include any other information that would be useful.

Comment: The intermittent nature of this smells to me like a connection limit on the MySQL server. Try bumping that up.